# Como empacotar e distribuir um sistema web?

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-desktop

Preciso que determinado sistema Web - incluindo o próprio servidor PHP, bem como o MySQL - sejam "empacotados" em um arquivo executável, permitindo dessa forma, que o usuário leigo utilize-o numa espécie de browser próprio. Quais etapas precisaria seguir para tornar este sistema distribuível?

**Edit**: O PHP e o MySQL posso instalar manualmente, mas ainda não sei como fazer para ter um browser para o sistema.

Comment: é realmente necessário utilizar um navegador que não esteja presente no sistema? Para o lado do servidor, até usaria algo como [Vagrant (em inglês)](http://www.vagrantup.com/) para virtualizar o ambiente, mas não consigo conceber opções para embarcar o navegador no pacote.

Comment: Sim, o browser próprio seria fundamental.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Considerando que você pode instalar o PHP e o MySQL no computador do seu cliente, então é só criar um domínio fake usando o arquivo hosts do Windows (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).

```
# Localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 meusite.dev
```

Mas precisa criar um virtual host pelo httpd.conf:

```conf
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName meusite.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Nome\Documents\.....\pasta_do_site"
</VirtualHost>
```

E pedir para ele visitar http://meusite.dev no browser.

A única outra alternativa que eu imagino, é hospedar o site em algum servidor de testes.

=============

**Edição: transformei meu comentário em resposta:**

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Instale o Google Chrome;
2. Abra o endereço de desenvolvimento;
3. Clique no ícone de três barrinhas no canto superior direito;
4. Escolha "Ferramentas > Criar atalho de aplicativos" e marque "Área de trabalho".

E pronto você tem um browser dedicado para o site em questão, sem botão voltar, barra de endereços, etc com ícone no desktop. Ver também http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser

O resultado fica assim:

[image: site com browser próprio]

Comment: Já pensei na possibilidade, mas falta-me o browser.

Comment: Mas o usuário não tem um navegador (browser) instalado?

Comment: Não. O navegador seria personalizado, para só abrir aquela página, sem barra de ferramentas, botão de voltar, ou algo assim, para o cliente não se distrair e abrir o facebook "sem querer".

Answer (score 6):

Uma solução alternativa seria criar um instalador próprio e incluir as sub-instalações dos programas necessários. O [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) é uma boa ferramenta para fazer isso.

## WAMP

O primeiro passo da instalação principal seria instalar um pacote WAMP, por exemplo, do [Bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/wamp). Para fazer isso sem intervenção do usuário executa-se o pacote com o parâmetro `--mode unnatended` ([fonte](http://bitnami.com/forums/forums/wampstack/topics/is-there-a-silent-switch-to-install-wamp)). A instalação principal poderia verificar se o pacote WAMP já está instalado e pular esta etapa em caso afirmativo.

Nesse primeiro passo, seria possível ainda instalar os aplicativos necessários separadamente. Apache, PHP e MySQL (até a versão em que eu usava, pelo menos) funcionam se executarmos os binários diretamente da pasta de instalação. Então na verdade, se houver tempo e necessidade, poderia-se criar um WAMP customizado, cuja vantagem é o tamanho menor do pacote e a menor quantidade de elementos desnecessários instalados no cliente.

## Navegador

Para a navegação, existem [tópicos](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2273837) em alguns fóruns sobre como deixar um *Firefox Portable* sem barras de ferramentas. Não cheguei a testar essa ideia, mas já usei a versão portável desse navegador e sei que funciona.

Outra opção seria criar um pequeno executável (em outra linguagem, é claro) com um navegador embutido. Há muitos anos eu costumava fazer isso em Delphi ou VB incluindo algumas DLL's que permitiam colocar um componente com o Internet Explorer dentro de uma janela. O programa somente precisa de uma janela simples que abra sempre o sistema na página inicial, embora seja possível incluir algumas funcionalidades interessantes, como uma janela especial para dados de login que então faz uma requisição para o servidor local antes de abrir o sistema em si ou um listener que faz o logout do usuário quando ele fecha a janela.

## Aplicação

Depois disso, é necessário extrair os arquivos da aplicação no diretório do WAMP, além dos arquivos de configuração necessários, que podem ser obtidos de uma instalação de teste.

Um último passo seria fazer criar a estrutura do banco de dados, o que pode ser feito ainda na instalação através de um script PHP de linha de comando ou no primeiro acesso da aplicação através de um *wizard* a là Wordpress.

## Atualização

E um epílogo nessa história seria fazer a atualização do sistema via PHP mesmo usando uma extensão de SVN ou GIT, ou mesmo baixando um zip da web.

## Alternativa: Máquina Virtual

Uma última alternativa que eu consideraria seria uma Máquina Virtual (VM) com o ambiente do sistema pré-configurado. No caso do Windows poderia ser criado um serviço associado a essa VM que a liga/desliga ou salva/restaura o seu estado quando o SO é iniciado ou desligado.

Existem sites que disponibilizam VMs enxutas baseadas em linux que podem ser usadas para tais propósitos. Por exemplo, o [TurnKey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack).

Answer (score 6):

Eu já fiz uns testes e gostei do [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/). Você cria o sistema com html, javascript, php etc, empacota e distribui para mac, linux e windows. Já vai com um navegador do SDK, não precisa mais nada. Estão migrando em breve para [tideKit](https://www.tidekit.com/)

Comment: Tive alguns problemas com o TideSDK há algum tempo, por isso engavetei o projeto. Vamos ver como o TideKit se sai.

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei um [**site**](http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-apps-desktop-2013/) que trás mais algumas alternativas além das já citadas aqui, bem como os prós e contras de cada uma, trazendo também seus principais recursos.

- [**AppJS**](http://appjs.org/), baseado no [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs);
- [**Node-webkit**](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), combina o Node.js e o webkit;
- [**Sencha Desktop**](https://www.sencha.com/products/sdp) (não é gratuito), baseado no webkit;
- [**Brackets Shell**](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell), utiliza o Chromium.