# App HTML Desktop com Node.JS + Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, aplicação-desktop

Estou precisando desenvolver uma app de chat baseada em HTML que se conecte com um servidor Node.JS que está rodando com Socket.IO.

Cheguei a desenvolver grande parte da app usando o TideSDK, porém na hora da integração de chamar o script do Socket.IO a app não carregava, por problemas do TideSDK.

Já testei o node-webkit, mas não funcionaram as notificações do webkit e não tenho certeza se há suporte para Socket.IO.

Alguém tem uma sugestão de plataforma para desenvolvimento de uma app HTML para Desktop?

Comment: Relacionado, quase duplicata (porém sua pergunta é mais específica): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1676/como-empacotar-e-distribuir-um-sistema-web

Comment: Você já tentou fazer a "casca" do seu aplicativo usando Adobe AIR? No passado eu utilizei com webview, a partir da versão 8 é possível utilizar esse recurso nativo. Se não tiver suporte oficial de algo no HTML, você pode criar wrappers, ele também suporta notifications, mas precisa de wrapper.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, eu optei na época por TideSDK por ter suporte ao Linux, já que até onde eu lembro, o AIR para Linux foi descontinuado.
Desde o ano passado falam do TideKit (https://www.tidekit.com/) que seria uma evolução do TideSDK e que suportaria Socket.IO e inclusive, apps mobile. Mas até hoje não lançaram ele.

Comment: Muito interessante, eu usei o Air no passado no linux, mas confesso que era uma tranqueira instalar. Não sabia dessa evolução pro TideSDK, até procurei algum projeto tipo um fork do Chrome pra isso, mas não achei, espero realmente que alguém ache e responda sua pergunta, pois seria útil pra mim também.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, eu tive uma ideia alguns minutos atrás, pode não ser a melhor solução, mas ainda assim é uma solução:
Google Chrome Apps.

Comment: Então, eu já fiz extensions pra Chrome, é parecido com Apps, mas ele exige que o usuário tenha o google chrome instalado, achei que você estivesse procurando uma solução independente e instalável.

Comment: É, trabalhar dessa maneira realmente é meio chato por exigir o Google Chrome.

Comment: @Tomazio, você diz que desenvolveu a App usando o TideSDK e relata ter tido problema na Integração com Socket IO mas não diz qual foi esse problema. A Integração depende do protocolo e método de transporte do Socket IO que aceita vários tipos diferentes. Você consegue postar uma prova de conceito simples demonstarnado onde o problema ocorre ? Talvez o problema esteja na configuração do transporte adequado.

Comment: @JoãoParaná, ele carregava os scripts JS antes de carregar o JS do Socket.IO, mas com o node-webkit não ocorreu esse problema.

Comment: Ok @Tomazio trabalhar no paradigma de Load Assincrono tem desses problemas. Você deve dar uma atenção especial a estas race-conditions no seu código. Tente usar os Eventos do Socket IO para informar que seu código pode ser Carregado de forma segura. Assim funcionará sempre.

Answer (score 1):

É realmente um problema ser uma aplicação Web?

Veja: o Node.js foi feito para a Web. O Html5 está sendo desenvolvido para melhorar as aplicações web. Enquanto o Html5 não é totalmente equivalente ao potencial de uma aplicação Desktop bem-feita, ele é suficiente para a maioria dos casos.

Não quero dar opinião aqui, quero dar uma solução mesmo. O Node.js é uma plataforma para desenvolvimento **web**. Se você não quer usar web, podes arriscar-se a criar wrappers para GTK ou WxWidgets, suportados pelo C++, por exemplo. (Caso não saibas, o Node.js suporta nativamente add-ons feitos em C++)

Tenha em mente que se usar Node.js, tua aplicação será web. Podes "fingir" que é desktop para teus clientes, mas no fundo Node.js é web.

Se teu cliente não dispõe de acesso à rede, podes criar um pacote que instala e configura (caso necessário) tua aplicação junto ao Node em sua máquina (ou você mesmo pode instalar, se não quiser se aventurar criando instaladores). Depois, criar um atalho para abrir o navegador em tua aplicação não será problema.

Já se teu cliente dispõe de acesso e está disposto a te pagar a hospedagem, podes hospedar tua aplicação em um servidor na nuvem. Já existem servidores Node de bom preço e qualidade hoje em dia.

Um último ponto: Se não queres suportar todos os navegadores (dar suporte a todas as versões do IE sempre foi um problema), não precisas. Peça ao cliente que instale um navegador gratuito como o Google Chrome ou o Firefox. Isso não deveria incomodar teu cliente. Todas as aplicações desktop dependem de instalador: sistemas de gestão, aplicações de escritório, jogos, até extensões para aplicações desktop dependem de uma instalação. Porque que teu aplicativo não pode depender de uma, também?

Comment: o meu backend já é todo em Node.JS + Socket.IO, o problema de migrar a parte web para é o suporte das ferramentas de "conversão" com o Socket.IO.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quis dizer com esse comentário. Pode elaborar um pouco melhor pra que eu possa melhorar minha resposta?

Comment: André, o foco da minha app é ser desktop, a aplicação Web eu já tenho. A minha questão é, migrar ela 100% funcional para o desktop usando apenas HTML.

Comment: Se é pra usar HTML, porque não usar um navegador? Bem... se tua aplicação roda no Internet Explorer, uma solução é disfarçá-lo com uma aplicação [.hta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Pois eu quero que ela rode na maior quantidade de dispositivos que puder, computadores com Windows, Mac OS, Linux e futuramente até telefones.
Por isso procuro uma solução do tipo TideSDK, atualmente estou testando o node-webkit.

Comment: Se ele rodar em navegadores, ele roda na quantidade de dispositivos que suportar um navegador (hoje em dia, eu diria que todos). Ainda não entendo qual o problema...

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13024/discussion-between-tomazio-and-andre-leria)

Answer (score 1):

Porque vc não continua exatamente como está e rode em cima de uma webview do javaFx?
Como os phonegaps da vida fazem!
Vai rodar até em cafeteira e com java + javascript + webview.engine do javafx você tem acesso as bibliotecas Java como system.io e etc...

Dê uma olhada nisso:
https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx